# How to pass String value from sub method to main method in java?

Tags: java

```
public class NewTest {
    @Test
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        new NewTest();
        NewTest.test();
        System.out.println(myname);
    }
    public static void test(){
        String myname = "Sivarajan";
    }
}
```

How to print `myname`? Initialization error appeared while running this program.

Comment: You would do well by reading through a tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Since `myname` is declared and initialized inside of `test()` you can't access it elsewhere. If you want to use that variable elsewhere you can define it as a class variable.

Comment: @tsivarajan Please provide some feedback on the answers provided so we can see if this question is solved or not.

Answer (score 1):

Java variables have different **scopes**. If you define a variable inside a method it is non usable inside another method.

ways to fix it in your code:

## 1 Make the variable a member class

```
 public class NewTest {

    public static String myname = "Sivarajan";

    @Test
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException  
    {
        /*Note that since you are working with static methods 
         and variables you don't have to instantiate any class*/
        System.out.println(myname);
    }
```

## 2 Make `test` return a String

```
public class NewTest {

    @Test
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException  
    {
        NewTest newt = new NewTest();
        System.out.println(newt.test());
    }

    //Note that we did remove the static modifier
    public String test(){
        String myname = "Sivarajan";
        return myName;
        //or simply return "Sivarajan";
    }
}
```

Further reading:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm

Comment: Your second solution won't currently compile, your method says it returns a type of String but you've only created a new variable, not returned it.

Comment: I AGREE YOUR POINT @Averroes

Answer (score 0):

Because your variable `myname` is declared and initialized inside of the `test()` method, it is unusable anywhere else in your program. You could have the `test()` method return a String like this:

```
public class NewTest {
    @Test
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        new NewTest();
        NewTest.test();
        System.out.println(test());
    }
    public static String test() { //Changed to return a String
        return "Sivarajan";
    }
}
```

or declare it as a class variable and then use it in all methods of the class thereafter

```
public class NewTest {
    String myname = "Sivarajan"; //added myname as a class variable

    @Test
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        new NewTest();
        NewTest.test();
        System.out.println(myname); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to pass the value from sub method to main method. @Takendarkk

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to achieve involves using 'fields' of an object.  What you have done is declared a variable inside a method, meaning it can only be referenced inside that method.  By declaring a field you can then create objects of your class, and each one will have that field to access, like the below:

```
   public class NewTest {
      public static void main(String [] args) {
        //Create NewTest object
        NewTest  tester = new NewTest();

        //Run the method on our new Object
        tester.test();

        //Print the field which we just set
        System.out.println(tester.myName);
      }

      //Set the field
      public void test(){
        myName = "Sivarajan";
      }

     //A public field which is accessible in any NewTest object that you create
     public String myName = "";
  }
```